# How to pause and resume a NodeJS pipeline of streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm using a promisified version of node's stream.pipleline:

```
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

//Create Read,Transform and Write streams....

await pipeline(read, progress,write )
```

I would like to be able to pause/resume the entire process programmatically. How can this be achieved, without breaking one of the streams?

Answer (score 0):

Well - it's actually quite simple - `pipeline` uses `pipe` underneath and that forwards your `pause`/`resume` logic between streams, so:

If you want to pause the reading:

```js
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

//Create Read,Transform and Write streams....

await pipeline(read, progress,write )

// under some circumstances:
read.pause();
// and then, when you're ready just
read.resume();
```

You can pause on any of the streams in pipeline except the writable one. Calling pause on `progress` will result in pausing the `read` as soon as the `highWaterMark` is reached (essentially when the buffer is full).